# Rename and/or Change Path to scriptresource.axd

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, httphandler

We have a requirement that the root of our site is actually at domain.com/xyz/ and we can't have /xyz/ be a virtual directory. Some modules in our site are leveraging the ScriptManager which is by default trying to reference domain.com/scriptresource.axd?blah=blah. The scriptresource.axd will not be resolved in this case. We have made it so the references to scriptresource.axd are now change before getting sent to the client to be /xyz/scriptresource.axd but this isn't working.

My suspicion is the ScriptResource Handler Mapping is not picking up the call because of the xyz. I have tried to update the Handler mapping using IIS Manager or by editing the \inetsrv\config\applicationhost.config, \frameworkv4.blah\web.config and \framework64\v4blah\web.config but these seem to not work either.

Can someone tell me how I could get the ScriptResource handler to handle something other than /scriptresource.axd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with `urlMappings` with something like:

```
<system.web>
<urlMappings enabled="true">
    <add url="~/xyz/default.aspx"
    mappedUrl="~/scriptresource.axd"/>
</urlMappings>
...
```

Comment: That works, thanks Dalorzo. Not sure why the handler path didn't work but I am just glad this works. thanks for the approach. I am using IIS 7 so for those in the same boat make sure you download the URL Rewrite Module and then the rules will be in the <system.webserver> node.